# Swift Charts - changing the X axis literals

Tags: swiftui, charts

I am moving my charts over from Daniel Gindi to Apple's Chart and haven't worked out how to control the X axis labels.

The X axis generates a daily angle from day 1 to 365 for the year, so is an integer. I want to  display the months of the year, as shown in the previous version of the chart.

[image]

Is it possible to use .chartXScale for this purpose? I am not sure how to get it to accept strings or if I need to try a different approach.

```
        var monthValues: [String] = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sept","Oct","Nov","Dec"]

        Chart{
            ForEach(dayTilt) {item in
                LineMark(
                ...      
                )  
        }
        .frame(height: 360)
        .chartXScale(domain: monthValues[0...11])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably store a `Date` rather than an `Int` for a day, so something like:

```
struct DayTilt: Identifiable {
    
    internal init(day: Int, value: Float) {
        date = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(day: day))!
        self.value = value
    }
    
    let id = UUID()
    let date: Date
    let value: Float
}
```

then you can use the following `PlottableValue`

```
value(_:date:unit:calendar:)
```

e.g.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var dayTilts: [DayTilt] = …
    
    var body: some View {
        Chart(dayTilts) { dayTilt in
            LineMark(x: .value("Date", dayTilt.date, unit: .day),
                     y: .value("Angle", dayTilt.value))
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are right in that converting the x-axis from and Int to a Date is the solution. The underlying question is, is it possible in the current SwiftUI to retitle the increments along either axis?

Comment: Take a look at `.chartXAxis`, `.chartXAxisLabel`, `.chartXScale`